# Image is not showing, what is wrong over here?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

This is my template. The problem is - the image is not displayed.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<main class="mt-5 pt-4">
<div class="container dark-grey-text mt-5">
  <div class="row wow fadeIn">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">

      <img src= "/media_root/Brush_Head.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" > <<<<---- this image is not showing

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
      <div class="p-4">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <a href="">
            <span class="badge purple mr-1">{{ object.get_category_display }}</span>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: If it works with an online link, so probably the **file path** is wrong. I suggest to read [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp). Maybe that could help you solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Badhon! You will get better help if you edit your question a bit. Start with a more focused title, and consider adding a bit of background before the code snippet: what are you trying to do? Have you tried any fixes yet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.